# Javascript non-enumerable property

Tags: javascript

How to create non-enumerable property on an object so that it won't show up in a for..in loop , but otherwise would be accessible using *Object.property* syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) for the task. Beside `enumerable`, you can also set `writable` and `configurable` (deletable) properties.

```js
var obj = {a: 1};

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'b', {
  value: 2,
  enumerable: false,
});

console.log(obj.b); //2
for (var key in obj) {
  alert(key); //just 'a'
}
```